# Is it safe to use urllib to determine if a site is unresponsive?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I was assigned a task of taking a list of 25k websites and removing the ones which are down/unresponsive. I figured the easiest way to do this:

```
with website in websites:
    try:
        req = Request(test, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux i686)"})
        with contextlib.closing(urlopen(req)) as response:
            new_list.add(response.geturl())   
    except:
        print(website + " removed")
```

How safe is this? The list contains many spam sites, and I don't think it's a good idea to send my IP address to them.

Is there an safer option I can take?

Comment: _How safe is this?_, what do you mean by **safe** ?

Comment: If you don't want to expose your IP address, don't connect. You can use a VPN to hide your immediate IP address but some sites will detect this and refuse your connection, or show different content than you would otherwise see.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Is there anything I need to worry about when opening 25k random sites with urllib?

Comment: @tripleee thank you. I don't really care about the content that is returned, just need to know if the site is responsive or not. I haven't used a vpn before. Do I simply download and setup something like nordVPN, or is there something I need to configure with the urllib library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about leaking your ip address I would suggest using a proxy server to request the sites. You can get proxies for free on some sites around the web. You can also use a vpn to run the script.

Here are the urllib docs on proxy handling

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.ProxyHandler